# Listing USB devices using libusb win32

Tags: c++, libusb

All I am trying to do is list usb devices using libusb win32 and I am having so much trouble.  I am using c++ and minGW.  Here is my simple program that will compile but will not list anything.  If anyone could tell me where to go from here it would be greatly appreciated.

```
cout << "\nFinding Devices..." << endl;
    struct usb_bus *busses;

    usb_init();
    usb_find_busses();
    usb_find_devices();

    busses = usb_get_busses();
    usb_set_debug(3);
    struct usb_bus *bus;
    int  c, i, a;
    for (bus = busses; bus; bus->next){
        struct usb_device *dev;

        for (dev = bus->devices; dev; dev = dev->next){
            if (dev->descriptor.bDeviceClass == 7){
                usb_dev_handle usb_open(struct usb_device *dev);
                int usb_set_configuration(usb_dev_handle *dev, int configuration);
            }}}
```

Comment: Try `bus = bus->next` in the first `for` loop.

Comment: I'd expect the above code to loop infinitely (supposing, of course, that your computer *has* a USB subsystem...)

Comment: I'd also suggest that checking return codes of functions is good programming practice, rather than just assuming they have succeeded.  `usb_find_busses` and `usb_find_devices` both return the number of busses/devices they found (on the first call).  You should probably check that this isn't zero.

Comment: I checked and I guess the program does not find any busses.  I obviously have my device plugged into the computer so can you help me with this. @tom

Comment: Have you fixed the first bug I pointed out?

Comment: Yes my for loop is 'for(bus = busses; bus; bus = bus->next)'

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that what is probably going on is that your device has class 0 - which means that the class is defined at the interface level, not at the device level.  For instance, this is what `lsusb` reports for my Microsoft keyboard:

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x07f8 
  bcdDevice            3.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
...
```

See how the device has `bDeviceClass` set to `0 (Defined at Interface level)` and each interface has its own `bInterfaceClass` set?

The easiest way to figure out what's going on is to find libusb.exe for Windows and run it with the `-v` flag to dump detailed information for each device.